# Can multiple threads be created to handle multiple task in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Can a thread be created to keep the queue populated with lines from the source file, text.txt, as well as simultaneously write the results to the output file tagfile.csv when the tagreset value is equal to the size of the tagdict?

```
tagdict = {}
tagreset = 10

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if (len(tagdict) == tagreset):
            tagfile = open("tagfile.csv","a")
            for key in tagdict:
                tagstring = ':' + (int(tagdict[key])-1) + '"\n"' + key + '","' + tagdict[key]
                tagfile.write(tagstring)
                tagfile.close()
                tagdict = {}
        q.put(line)

def worker(queue):
    mutex.acquire()
    try:
        queue_full = True
        while queue_full:
        try:
            for match in re.finditer('\<tag\>(.*?)\<\/tag\>',line):
                try:
                    tagdict[match.group(0)] = match.start()
                except:
                    print "no title matches found"
        except Queue.Empty:
            queue_full = False
    finally:
        mutex.release()
thread_count = 5
for i in range(thread_count):
    t = Thread(target=worker, args = (q,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: Why would you use multiple threads with all the required synchronization overhead to implement a simple filter?

Comment: I'm scanning a large file with a low performance computer

Comment: But unless your computer uses an SSD (unlikely if it's "low performance") most of the time would be spent waiting for the hard drive anyway. More threads won't make the disk spin faster.

Comment: The threads are in use so I can scan multiple pieces of the file simultaneously opposed to scanning one line at a time with the assumption that it would be faster. Am I wrong in making that assumption?